# Create recursive zod schema

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, zod

i am currently working on a zod schema which looks like this:

```
export const ActionTypeValidator = z.object({
  action: z.any(),
  state: z.any(),
  actionGroups: z.array(ActionGroupTypeValidator).optional(),
})
export type ActionType = z.infer<typeof ActionTypeValidator>

export const ActionGroupTypeValidator = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  name: z.string(),
  actions: z.array(ActionTypeValidator),
})
export type ActionGroupType = z.infer<typeof ActionGroupTypeValidator>
```

I get the following two errors:

1. Vue: ActionTypeValidator implicitly has type any because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
2. Vue: ActionGroupTypeValidator implicitly has type any because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

I already tried a lot with `z.lazy` but i can't get this stuff to work.
Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a working solution now.

```
const InternalActionTypeValidator = z.object({
  action: z.any(),
  state: z.any(),
})
type InternalActionType = z.infer<typeof InternalActionTypeValidator> & {
  actionGroups?: z.infer<typeof ActionGroupTypeValidator>
}

export const ActionTypeValidator = InternalActionTypeValidator.extend({
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define
  actionGroups: z.lazy(() => ActionGroupTypeValidator).optional(),
})
export type ActionType = z.infer<typeof ActionTypeValidator>

export const ActionGroupTypeValidator = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  name: z.string(),
  actions: z.array(ActionTypeValidator),
})
export type ActionGroupType = z.infer<typeof ActionGroupTypeValidator>
```

The secret was the combination of `z.lazy` and extending the `InternalActionType` with

```
& {
      actionGroups?: z.infer<typeof ActionGroupTypeValidator>
    }
```